# Solution against motorcycle gasoline theft?

Tags: motorcycle

During these last few weeks, somebody has been stealing gas from my motorcycle.
It's a Honda Vt 125 Shadow, and since all the wires and hoses are apparent, it's pretty easy to unplug the hose and siphon gas from the tank.

Any ideas on how to prevent this ?!

Thanks

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably put a sticker on the gas tank that said something like 'Use Kerosene fuel only'

Comment: If it is the same people each time, then go to a chemistry site and ask what you can add to the fuel that will make it smell of 10 day old nappies (dippers).

Comment: Put diesel in the tank.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of after market anti gasoline theft locks available especially for Honda motorcycles,

Its basically a simple valve which doubles up as your gasoline open/close valve you need to use your key to open the valve to gasoline from the tank into the engine.

Basically a key hole will be there instead of the manual valve in the below image.
You insert the key , turn to unlock (let petrol in) lock (stop the flow)

[image]

There is also this extensive DIY which you can do if you are into DIY much.

[Anti Gasoline Theft System](http://www.slideshare.net/mohitmahaldar/fuel-theft-prevention-system)

Comment: Great info! The link you provided opens the image you embedded in your answer and not to the DIY you mention.

Comment: Yeah just now noticed, edited , Please check it now..

Comment: Actually , if you live in india you dont even need the DIY , you just go to a dealer and ask petrol lock and he will install it in your bike costs around 175 bucks.. or $2.75 .

Answer (score 3):

I do like @Tims' idea of the sticker. You don't have to make it theftproof just more difficult than the bike next to yours. If the fuel line is held on with a spring type hose clamp replace it with a wormdrive clamp. Fill in the screwdriver slot of the clamp with epoxy or something similar. This will mean a socket or nutdriver will be required to remove the clamp, which is something most people don't carry in their pocket. It won't be impossible to remove, but hopefully difficult enough that the thieves choose somewhere easier.