# Which of these parts can protect my gasoline from theft?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, locks, fuel-tank, theft-prevention

I am aware of [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5163/solution-against-motorcycle-gasoline-theft), and I believe the answer there is excellent. But what I'm asking for is the list below and what to make of it.

Some people in my neighbourhood have been stealing gasoline from [my motorcycle.](http://www.bikewale.com/honda-bikes/cbtwister/) (One of my friends caught them red handed the other day, and they fled.) They did it by switching a lever and disconnecting this hose so that they could drain it out into a container.

[image]
I figure I need some sort of lock. But none of the local shops have this type of lock for my particular model of motorcycle.

So I searched for it online, and I found [this list](http://www.vicky.in/accessories/honda-cb-twister-bike-accessories/) in an online store.

> Body Cover
>   Buzzer
>   Craush (sic) Guard
>   Engine Guard
>   Front Guard
>   Front Inner Box
>   Gear Lever
>   Hand Grip
>   Pillion Holder
>   Scooter Body Cover
>   Tank Cover

Will any of these parts protect my bike from such theft? I have searched everywhere for a petrol lock for my particular model.

If anyone has any other suggestions for how to prevent this, that's welcome too. Feel free to ping me in chat also.

Comment: It's too bad you couldn't get a locking lever to replace the one which is there. Turn the lever to off, insert key, turn key, no more stolen gas. I'm sure you'd have to have something special made to do it, but it sounds like a good idea :o) ... hopefully @DucatiKiller will be on with some ideas. He's pretty handy in the MC department.

Comment: Interesting problem.  I wish I had a solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

You could take the screw out of the center of the knob. Remove it, then put it on only to shut off or turn on the fuel.

Comment: This sounds like a cool idea. I'll try it.